# Expectation regarding Brownian Motion

Tags: probability, brownian-motion

This is a formula regarding getting expectation under the topic of Brownian Motion.

\begin{align}
E[W(s)W(t)] &= E[W(s)(W(t) - W(s)) + W(s)^2] \\
&= E[W (s)]E[W (t) - W (s)] + E[W(s)^2]
\\
&= 0+s\\
&=\min(s,t)
\end{align}

How does $E[W (s)]E[W (t) - W (s)]$ turn into 0?

Thanks alot!! Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: It's a product of independent increments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$W(s)\sim N(0,s)$ and $W(t)-W(s)\sim N(0,t-s)$.  So both expectations are $0$.

(The step that says $\mathbb E[W(s)(W(t)-W(s))]= \mathbb E[W(s)] \mathbb E[W(t)-W(s)]$ depends on an assumption that $t>s$.)

Answer (score 3):

Brownian motion has independent increments. This means the two random variables $W(t_1)$ and $W(t_2-t_1)$ are independent for every $t_1 < t_2$.

Independence for two random variables $X$ and $Y$ results into $E[X Y]=E[X] E[Y]$. This is zero if either $X$ or $Y$ has mean zero. Now, remember that for a Brownian motion $W(t)$ has a normal distribution with mean zero.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is very helpful.