# Expectation of Brownian Motion. How assumption of t>s affects an equation derivation.

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

This question is regarding an answer to the question below:

[Expectation regarding Brownian Motion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/247655/expectation-regarding-brownian-motion)

This is a formula regarding getting expectation under the topic of Brownian Motion.
$$
\begin{align*}
E[W(s)W(t)]
&=E[W(s)(W(t)−W(s))+W(s)^2]\\
&=E[W(s)]E[W(t)−W(s)]+E[W(s)^2]\\
&=0+s
=\min(s,t).
\end{align*}
$$

One of Michael Hardy's comment is: 
"The step that says $$E[W(s)(W(t)−W(s))]=E[W(s)]E[W(t)−W(s)]$$ depends on an assumption that $t>s$."

So, finally, my question is how does the assumption $t>s$ play out in the 
$$E[W(s)(W(t)−W(s))]=E[W(s)]E[W(t)−W(s)]?$$

What if $t\leq s$?

Thanks a lot! Love the smart math stack exchange crowd!

Comment: Which definition of Brownian motion have you been exposed to?

Comment: this question is under the brownian motion as Gaussian process. thx

Comment: ?? Sorry but this is quite insufficient to **characterize** Brownian motion... Surely you know more than this on the subject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $t>s$ you know from the definition of a Brownian Motion that $W_t-W_s$ is independent of $W_s$ and this implies

$$\mathbb{E}(W_s \cdot (W_t-W_s)) = \mathbb{E}(W_s) \cdot \mathbb{E}(W_t-W_s)$$

If $t \leq s$ that's not true, but you can use

$$\mathbb{E}(W_s \cdot W_t) = \mathbb{E}((W_s-W_t) \cdot W_t +W_t^2)$$

instead (where $W_s-W_t$ is now independent of $W_t$) and do the same calculations as above.